# How to determine if a worker in a supervision tree is starting for the very first time or has been restarted

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have a simple supervisor configuration:

```
-module(my_supervisor).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).

init(_Args) ->
    {ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10},
       [
        {my_worker, {my_worker, start_link, []}, permanent, 5000, worker, [my_worker]}
        ]
     }
}.
```

And even simple worker:

```
-module(my_worker).
-export([start_link/0]).
start_link() ->
    %??? is this the first time the supervisor is starting me or have I crashed and been restarted???
```

So is it even possible to determine whether this is the first time the start_link function is called by the supervisor or the worker process has crashed sometime in the past and is now being restarted?

Comment: Often, you can write my_worker such that it always thinks it has been started for the first time and recreates its assumptions based on that. That will make it less important to know the current start-state of my_worker. If you want to count this, do it outside the process and supervision tree in an ETS table or by a counting process which you ping whenever you restart.

Comment: I think this is only possible if you use some sort of side-effect strategy - ping ( and increment) a counting process, increment a record in an ets table (as mentioned in the comment to your OP), etc. All of which makes me curious as to why you care? What problem are you trying to solve by knowing that a worker was restarted?

Answer (score 0):

1. For determining whether this is the first time the `start_link` function is called by the supervisor.
   You can use `childId` parameter and pass the `childId` from outside as follows, for details, please doc about  [erlang supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html).

   start_child(ChildId, Mod, Args) ->
       {ok, _} = supervisor:start_child(?SERVER,
                                        {ChildId, {Mod, start_link, Args},
                                         transient, ?MAX_WAIT, worker, [Mod]}),
       ok.
2. For determining `worker` has been restarted. Please read document of [monitor and link](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html). When crash happens，your process will receive messages. If you read the `supervisor`'s source code, you will find the supervisor actually use `link and monitor` to solve the `crash` monitor task.

3.

```
init([]) -> 
     process_flag(trap_exit, true), 
     ...


terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    % may be crash here by check reason above. 
    ok.

handle_info({'EXIT',Self,Reason},State#state{self=Self)->
    error_logger:info_report([crash_now]),
    {stop,Reason,State};



  [1]: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html
```

Comment: 1. start_child(ChildId, Mod, Args) -> {ok, _} = supervisor:start_child(?SERVER, {ChildId, {Mod, start_link, Args}, transient, ?MAX_WAIT, worker, [Mod]}), ok.
Args will be passed to the start_link callback function every time the process is restarting including the first time it is started so I don't get how this is going to help me. The arguments are always going to be the same.

   2. I don't want to monitor my worker process explicitly (that's what the supervisor is for) I just what the supervisor to tell me if I've crashed before.

Comment: I have added item 3 for your crash-cared process

Comment: Again, I don't want to monitor the process myself, I don't want to trap_exits and link. What I want is for the supervisor to do all that work for me and provide me with the necessary information about what's going on.

Comment: Maybe SASL is what you want. It writes down crash information in error_logger event manager, you can get crash event from there.